# Why is my system freezing, thus forcing a hard restart?

Tags: xubuntu, freeze

The system I am using as an entertainment PC sometimes freezes unexpectedly, and I need to restart it. It is running MythTV, so it is on 24/7.

I currently am working around this problem with a cron job that reboots the machine once a day. Even with this work-around, it sometimes still freezes. I realize this is an imperfect solution, and I would like to solve whatever the underlying problem is.

If I am using the system when this happens, the screen will freeze, then any audio playing will stop. The mouse cursor will keep moving, but nothing will respond to clicks. If I act quickly enough, Alt+PrtSc REISUB will restart, but if this freeze happens when I am not using the machine, I have to had restart it by pushing the power button.

I am running Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and I had this same problem when I was runnign 16.04

Specs:

RAM: CORSAIR Vengeance LPX 16GB (2 x 8GB) 288-Pin DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 2133 (PC4 17000) Desktop Memory Model CMK16GX4M2A2133C13R

CPU: AMD RYZEN 5 1500X 4-Core 3.5 GHz (3.7 GHz Turbo) Socket AM4 65W YD150XBBAEBOX Desktop Processor

Motherboard: ASRock X470 Master SLI/AC AM4 AMD Promontory X470 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 HDMI ATX AMD Motherboard
Graphics Card: MSI GeForce GT 730 DirectX 12 N730K-1GD5LP/OC
3 hard drives, all HDD: One 160 GB boot drive and two 4 TB storage drives

I have searched on Google and sites like this, but I have not found a similar problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the final lines from the syslog before one of the freezes:

```
Sep  3 18:26:22 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for fe8
0::d5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 18:26:29 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d1
9f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 18:26:29 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d
5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 18:26:29 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for 200
2:d19f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 18:35:24 Dipper wpa_supplicant[766]: wlp30s0: WPA: Group rekeying complet
ed with c0:c1:c0:a9:ff:ad [GTK=CCMP]
Sep  3 18:35:24 Dipper wpa_supplicant[766]: wlp30s0: WPA: Group rekeying complet
ed with c0:c1:c0:a9:ff:ad [GTK=CCMP]
Sep  3 18:39:01 Dipper CRON[7432]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean 
] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep  3 18:39:03 Dipper systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep  3 18:39:03 Dipper systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Sep  3 18:39:40 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d1
9f:d1d8:0:1f7e:82bf:256:69bb on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 18:39:40 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for 200
2:d19f:d1d8:0:1f7e:82bf:256:69bb on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 18:39:40 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for fe8
0::d5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 18:39:41 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d1
9f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 18:39:41 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d
5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 18:39:41 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for 200
2:d19f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 19:04:53 Dipper systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Sep  3 19:04:53 Dipper anacron[9110]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-09-03
Sep  3 19:04:53 Dipper anacron[9110]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Sep  3 19:09:01 Dipper CRON[9468]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean 
] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Sep  3 19:09:03 Dipper systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Sep  3 19:09:03 Dipper systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Sep  3 19:17:01 Dipper CRON[9914]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /et
c/cron.hourly)
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d19f:d1d8:0:1f7e:82bf:256:69bb on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for 2002:d19f:d1d8:0:1f7e:82bf:256:69bb on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for fe80::d5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.*.
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d19f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.
Sep  3 19:18:28 Dipper avahi-daemon[784]: Registering new address record for 2002:d19f:d1d8:0:5156:aa72:e3f4:352a on wlp30s0.*.
```

More recently, it seems to have frozen during one of the cron job reboots:

```
Jul 18 09:08:59 Dipper lircd-0.10.0[936]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/i
nput[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper lircd[936]: lircd-0.10.0[936]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/cl
ass/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper lircd-0.10.0[936]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/i
nput[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper avahi-daemon[810]: Withdrawing address record for 2002:d1
9f:d1d8:0:c147:877e:e046:faf on wlp30s0.
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper avahi-daemon[810]: Registering new address record for 200
2:d19f:d1d8:0:c147:877e:e046:faf on wlp30s0.*.
Jul 18 09:09:00 Dipper avahi-daemon[810]: Registering new address record for fe8
0::d5bd:8e29:4d2b:bb01 on wlp30s0.*.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper CRON[11399]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
 ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper CRON[11400]: (root) CMD (/sbin/reboot)
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 PV scan on device 8:1...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Discard unused blocks once a week.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Clean PHP session files every 30 mins
.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Message of the Day.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Location Lookup Service...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Trigger anacron every hour.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for power management...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for generating UUIDs...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1]: Stopping RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jul 18 09:09:01 Dipper systemd[1310]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor..
```

.

---

Adding output of `free -h` as requested

```
kittens@Dipper:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        905M        8.6G         19M        6.2G         14G
Swap:          979M          0B        979M
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Also, research this... AMD had a recall for certain RYZEN processors running Linux... I don't know if yours is included... but check it out.

Comment: I added the results of `free -h`. As far as I could find the recall applies to Ryzen 7 chips, and I have a Ryzen 5.

Comment: Your swap is way too small. Resize it to 4G. Also check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site to check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: My 1st attempt to increase swap space backfired, thanks to my inexperience and neglecting to make a backup first. I had to reinstall the OS. However, now that it is reinstalled, I have increased my swap space to 24G, which is more than you suggested, but I have the space.  I did it by running sudo swapoff -a then following the instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04

I still need to re-install myhtv, etc., which will take some time. I will comment again after I have done that and run it long enough to see if this worked.

Comment: Now your swap is too big. Change it down to 4G as I recommended.

Comment: OK. I just changed it to 4G. Since this problem can take a day or so to manifest. I will need to wait for a few days to see if it worked.

Comment: No guarantee's, but it's a start. Does `free -h` now show 4G swap? We may also have to run `memtest` if there are more problems. Did you check your BIOS?

Comment: This is the output from `free -h`:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available`
`Mem:            15G        839M         12G        2.3M        2.6G         14G`
`Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G`

After I made the change, the system was up for more than 8 days before crashing and needing a restart again. 

I checked the BIOS, and it is not the latest version, but I think updating that is beyond my skill set.

If I have to set up a cron job to do a weekly reboot, I can live with that.

Comment: Updating the BIOS really isn't too difficult. Boot into Windows, download the newer BIOS, execute the update program, you're done. As always, it's always good to have good backups of your important files first.

Comment: I do not have Windows on this machine.

Comment: Some BIOS don't require Windows to update, and can be done via the current BIOS. You'll have to check.

Comment: It has been a while, but my system is still experiencing the problem I described. I don't think the BIOS is the issue because I had the same problem with an earlier motherboard. I suspect it is related to the mythtv software, since that has been the only constant in the system. I will be looking for help in those communities. Thank you for helping me narrow this down.

Comment: What version MythTV?

Comment: v29.1-13-g329c235

Comment: Can you try MythTV v30? That's the current stable version.